# MySQL Trigger with If loop and Signal

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Create a trigger that updates quantityInStock when an order is being placed (ie, subtract from quantityInStock the amount that is being ordered). It should also abort the order with an error message if there is not enough quantityInStock, to send an error message “not enough stock”. I am using MySQL and i have the version 5.7 and can't update it because its an old mac.

This is where I have gotten so far :

```
CREATE TRIGGER stocktest 
BEFORE UPDATE ON order details
FOR EACH ROW 
IF orderdetails.quantityOrdered < products.quantityInStock THEN 
UPDATE products SET products.quantityInStock = products.quantityInStock - NEW.quantityOrdered WHERE p.productCode = NEW.productCode 
ELSE IF od.quantityOrdered > p.quantityInStock THEN 
signal sqlstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'not enough stock' END IF;
```

This is my error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE IF od.quantityOrdered > p.quantityInStock THEN signal sqlstate '45000' SET ' at line 1
```

These are the tables :

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_classicmodels |
+-------------------------+
| costlist                |
| customers               |
| employees               |
| offices                 |
| orderdetails            |
| orders                  |
| paylist                 |
| payments                |
| productlines            |
| products                |
| unpaidlist              |
+-------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Multi-statement block needs in BEGIN-END. Each `IF` must have its own `END IF;`.

Comment: *trigger that updates quantityInStock when an order is being placed (ie, subtract from quantityInStock the amount that is being ordered).* This **must** be AFTER trigger. `quantityInStock ` must be updated only when `orderdetails` is updated. You cannot refer to `orderdetails.quantityOrdered` as scalar value.

Comment: *It should also abort the order with an error message if there is not enough quantityInStock* This must be provided by CHECK constraint in `products` table.